# tmux session closes when ssh terminal closes

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

***What I am trying to do:***
I am trying to execute couple of bash commands on a remote machine using ssh and I want those commands to finish execution even after ssh-session is closed in the middle of execution.

***What I have done so far :***
I am using Putty to connect to ssh (one of the reasons of using putty is that one machine is windows and remote machine is mac-os and I need some way to initiate ssh through Python command). I am passing command.txt file and it contains all the commands I want to execute.

```
putty -ssh start-ts@ip.000.001.101 -m command.txt ( not real ip)
```

command.txt : looks like this :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
echo $PATH; sleep 1
tmux -c 'queue.sh'
sleep 100
```

After connecting to ssh, to make sure that my script/commands continue running on remote machine even after ssh-session is closed on another machine, **I am using 'tmux'**

***But the Problem is :*** 
Even after using tmux, processes called by queue.sh terminate as soon as I close ssh-session.

I have also tried

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
echo $PATH; sleep 1
tmux
queue.sh
sleep 100
```

does the same thing.

***What I also tried :*** 
If I just pass following commands using ssh (in command.txt)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
echo $PATH; sleep 1
tmux
```

and then manually type queue.sh in tmux terminal, is that case I can close ssh-terminal and remote machine continues execution of processes.

***Any suggestion ?*** 
I want to be able to pass everything though script files and keeping the processes running on remote machine (mac-os) even after closing ssh-session on another machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-c` option doesn't actually start a new session; it's for compatibility with other shells if you use `tmux` as a login shell. In order to run `queue.sh` in a `tmux` session, try starting `tmux` with

```
tmux new-session queue.sh
```

Comment: Great! thank you, Chepner. (I dont have enough rating to rate this answer.)

Comment: @user2259784 you do now. It would be great if you could also accept this answer, assuming it solved your issue, so the question can be marked as solved.